# WP Run periodictask every 5 minute

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-agents, periodic-task

I've made an WP app, that checks in-game events of Guild Wars two. Looking up, MSDN states that the task will be run every 30 minute. Thing is, at 30 minute, an event might already be over, is there away to make it run 5 minute, or an alternative?

All the task needs to do, it download some text from a webpage and display a notification if an event is due.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to make a periodic task run at shorter intervals.

The only alternative is using the push notifications, but it means that you need to host a server somewhere (or use a cloud-based service, like [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/)) to send the notifications.

Comment: Well, I got MSDN, which mean I got an Azure subscription, would I be able to use one of the services they offer to do push notifications?

Comment: @Jazerix Yes, using Azure Mobile Services: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-wp8/

Answer (score 0):

To run more frequently then the normal background task schedule, you'd either need to "run under lockscreen" and handle it yourself, or offload the workload to a server that can create push notifications for you.